# Is it possible for this kind of solid state relay to drive high side?

Tags: mosfet, opto-isolator, solid-state-relay

I require a solid state relay to be able to switch high side, but also has low on-resistance.

G3VM has low on-resistance but it's application diagram shows exclusively low-side switch.

[image]

[image]

**Question:**

1. what is this configuration of FETs called ?
2. Since it's isolated, why it cannot be used as high side switches ?

Comment: Nothing that says they cant be used for high side other than your interpretation. They are simply back to back mosfets.

Comment: connection A shows a high side switch 50% of the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection C is the high side switch to the load, if DC negative terminal = pins 6,7 as shown.  Gnd is where you decide is 0V.

The Nch FETs are just ganged in parallel in "C" as a **common-source mode switch** (common to input and output) and switched drain.